# mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, string, mysqli

I have an issue with `mysqli_connect` expecting the parameter to be a string and apparently an array is given

I have a php file that writes the `mysqli_connect` information to a file from variables "userconnection.txt"

```
'localhost','root','','forum'
```

Then I have a standard php connection.php file with the added userconnection.txt file for the host user and password.

```
<?php

$connectionlink = file('userconnection.txt');
$connection = mysqli_connect($connectionlink);

if (!$connection) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

It spits out the error:

> `Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/forum/install files/connection.php on line 4
>   Connect Error:`

Comment: `mysqli_connect($connectionLink[0], $connectionLink[1], $connectionLink[2], $connectionLink[3]);`, that'd fix it. PHP will not `eval` things you read from a file (Imagine the horror if it would...), it'll just construct an array

Comment: If you want to use like this, first you need to `explode` the $connectionlink[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work and is actually a security risk.

**Security**

The txt file might be accessibe from your website via some URL. An attacker who know that URL (not difficult at all) can get the file and now has your login credentials.
Save the file outside your webroot or change it's extension and contents so they arent publcly avaiable. maybe a PHP file?

**Error**

You have two problems. First one is that `file` returns all lines of the file as individual lines and not as one string. Use `file_get_contents` instead.

Anyways, if you do this, you will still have all three parameters in one single variable of type string. But the `mysqli_connect` function needs three seperate variables and not one. You can fix this with a `explode`.

**Quick and dirty Solution**

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents('userconnection.txt');
$connectionvars = explode("," $filecontents);
$connection = mysqli_connect($connectionvars[0], $connectionvars[1], $connectionvars[2]);

if (!$connection) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

**Better but more complex solution**

Create a PHP file with your connection variables:

```
<?php
$DBHost = "host";
$DBUser = "user";
$DBPass = "pass";
```

change your connection file to this:

```
<?php
require("connectionsettings.php");
$connection = mysqli_connect($DBHost, $DBUser, $DBPass);
if (!$connection) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `file` functions return value is an array. Say `var_dump($connectionlink);`

That is much more better, if you store your parameters in variables or in constants. Use .php instead .txt, and include that file.

For example:

`include('connection.php');`

`$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));`

and in your connection.php

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASS', 'password of the user');
define('DB_NAME', 'name of your database');
```

Comment: constants have one drawback in this case. They are ... constant. So if you at some point want to add a second connection, your method wont work anymore. Just use plain old variables and require the file inside your scope as needed.

Comment: and what prevents you to define any number of constants? :) if you want more than one connection, you need to change the value of your variables every time, or define other variables. what is the difference?

Comment: The difference is, that you can not use the same "conect to db" function twice with different setting files as it uses the same constant names.

Comment: It's about design. You can use `function myConnect($host, $user, $pass) {//...} ` and then pass the constants.

Comment: This would only move the problem from inside the function to where you call the function. Constants are prone to many problems because of their lack of flexibility and decoupling, very similar to singletons. They have their use, but this IMHO is not one of them. But I guess this is way out of scope of this question now.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is in line with **$connection = mysqli_connect($connectionlink)**. Because variable isn't a string (In this case it's *'$connectionlink'*), so it shows the error.
In my situation I changed it to **$connection = mysqli_query($connectionlink)** and it solve everything.